# Distribute balls into boxes with rules

Tags: combinatorics

I am considering the following questions.

$\textbf{Q1: }$ I want to put all $n$ identical balls into $n$ boxes with name $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$. The rule is that, the number of balls in box $b_j$ should be less or equal to $j$, i.e. for box $b_2$, I can put at most $2$ balls into it. Then the question is how many ways I can put the balls?

$\textbf{Q2: }$With the same rule, if I put $m$ balls into the boxes where $m<n$, what is the total number of ways to do that?

$\textbf{Q3: }$Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the collection of all ways of $\textbf{Q2}$, and let $n(b_i,s)$ be the number of balls in box $b_i$ in way $s\in\mathcal{S}$, then how to calculate the total number of boxes with $k$ balls in it, i.e.
$$m(k)=\sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathcal{X}\big(n(b_i,s)=k\big)$$
where $\mathcal{X}$ is the indicator function.

Could you provide me some ideas about the above problems?

My attempt: I try to consider this as [stars and bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), but I'm not sure how to apply the rule to the bars.

---

New attempt: I solved $\textbf{Q1}$ and $\textbf{Q2}$. Indeed, $\textbf{Q1}$ is one case of $\textbf{Q2}$.

For $\textbf{Q2}$, we separate $m$ balls into the following situations,
$$(0,m),(1,m-1),(1,1,m-2),...,(2,m-2),(1,2,m-3),...$$
where each situation represents that, after putting the balls, what is the distribution of the balls, i.e. $(1,1,m-2)$ means $m-2$ balls in box $b_i$, while $b_j$ and $b_k$ each has only one ball for $i\neq j\neq k$. Then calculate the combination for each situation.

For instance, if $n=5$, then let $f_n(m)$ be the total number of ways that put exactly $m$ balls, then
\begin{align}
f(0)=&1\\
f(1)=&C_5^1=5\\
f(2)=&C_5^2+C_4^1=14\\
f(3)=&C_5^3+C_4^1C_4^1+C_3^1=29\\
f(4)=&C_5^4+C_4^2C_4^2+C_4^2+C_3^1C_4^1+C_2^1=49\\
f(5)=&C_5^5+C_4^1C_4^3+C_3^1C_4^2+C_4^2C_3^1+C_3^1C_3^1+C_2^1C_4^1+C_2^1=71\\
\end{align}
where $C_j^i=\binom{i}{j}$.